# PHP Email From Supplied Address

Tags: php, email, email-attachments

I have this PHP script I don't have much experience but I supply a email from, I want the email to be sent with that email address, it now uses the email address of my webhost account... what do I have to change?

```
<?PHP

$ai_to    = urldecode($_GET['to']);
$ai_from  = urldecode($_GET['fr']);
$ai_su    = urldecode($_GET['su']);
$ai_bo    = str_replace("CRLF","\n", urldecode($_GET['bo']));
$ai_fname = urldecode($_GET['fi']);
$ai_fpath = $ai_fname;

$header  = "From: " . 'aiapis mail svc:' . " <" . $ai_from . ">\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: " . $ai_from . "\r\n";

if ($ai_fname != '')
{
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
if (file_put_contents($ai_fpath, $data) === FALSE) die("Upload failed, sen cancelled.");
   $file_size = filesize($ai_fpath);

   if ($file_size > 10485760) die("> 10MB. Send cancelled.");


   $emtemp = 'emailtemp.log';
   $current = file_get_contents($emtemp);
   $current .= gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s") . ", " . $ai_fname . ", " . round($file_size/1048576, 3) . "MB\n";
   file_put_contents($emtemp, $current);   

   $handle = fopen($ai_fpath, "r");
   $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
   fclose($handle);
   $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

   $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

   $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
   $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
   $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
   $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
   $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
   $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
   $header .= $ai_bo."\r\n\r\n";
   $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
   $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$ai_fname."\"\r\n";
   $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
   $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$ai_fname."\"\r\n\r\n";
   $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
   $header .= "--".$uid."--";

   $sent = mail($ai_to, $ai_su, "", $header);
}
else $sent = mail($ai_to, $ai_su, $ai_bo, $header);

if ($sent)
{
   if ($ai_fname != '')
   {
      unlink($ai_fpath);
      echo "Email+attachment sent.";
   }
   else echo "Email sent.";
}
else echo "Mail server rejected email.";

?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php  "additional parameters"

Comment: The way I see it, your headers for `From` and `Reply-To` are set correctly. I think your web hosting provider might be overwriting these in their mail server while mail forwarding (usually a misconfiguration). It would be wise to check with them also. I have seen such instances in the past.

Answer (score 0):

The sender of the message is set at this line:

```
$header  = "From: " . 'aiapis mail svc:' . " <" . $ai_from . ">\r\n";
```

The variable `$ai_from` is set from a $_GET variable named "`fr`" (it comes from the URL like this: `http://www.google.com?fr=myemail@domain.net&to=touraddress@domain2.net`)

Does this script ever worked in the past?

If you are not familiar with the (30+ years old) email RFCs don't use the [PHP mail function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Use a library instead.

These two are popular: [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) and [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/). I prefer Swift Mailer but used both successfully. I also used `mail()` in the past because I had years of experience with mailers (in Delphi and other languages, so I knew the quirks).

If you sill want to use mail(), be aware that if you don't use it correctly in some cases your email can't be delivered with or without bounce (so you may not know it has failed). Also, emails sent with `mail()` are sometimes more prone to be delivered to the spam folder.

See [this example](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html) and send mail correctly the easy way in PHP.

By the way, I'm not affiliated with them.

Comment: I was lucky to have coded a (rather small) part of PHPMailer when I worked for its chief developer Andy Provost. It is a very flexible and powerful mailing lib for PHP :)

Comment: I just did test this script, it did work, but it did always send from the webhost email adress. Should I change the first code line you gave?

By the way, I use 000.webhost.com. I looked into the WebHost PHP Configs and it said:
sendmail_from = no value
sendmail_path = /usr/local/bin/phpsendmail

Comment: @user2012141 When you used Swift Mailer your used the setFrom() method and it got overwiten by your host? If this is the case instead of using sendmail use your SMTP server and this will work. See there: http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#using-the-smtp-transport